# download spring taglibs

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I want to use spring taglibs in UI layer in my project. 
Can anyone let me know where from i need to download the spring taglibs?

Answer (score 2):

They're shipped as part of the [Spring Framework distribution](http://www.springsource.org/download), you can find them packed inside the `dist/org.springframework.web.servlet` JAR file.

You don't usually have to unpack them, though, since the the appserver and IDE should auto-discover them inside the JAR file.

Comment: Yes, Its working. Just need to add the following in the jsp page.

Comment: Yes, Its working. Just need to add the following in the jsp page

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

and the spring related jar should be in classpath.
No need to add the .tld files into WEB-INF/taglib folder as we do in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

1. `spring-from.tld`path in `org.springframework.web.servlet-version.jar` 
   `meta-inf`
2. `org.springframework.web.servlet.version.jar` dependent on `org.springframework.web-version.jar`
   just download both jars and paste them in lib folder.
3. In jsp add the below line

   ```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
   <form: then it will show all tags or press ctrl with space bar.
   ```